# Update email domain in rails migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am new to Rails, I need to identify a way by which I can update domain of email for all records in the User table.

For instance User table has email column which has @xyz.com domain for all the records in User table. I want to change this domain to a new domain .i.e. @abc.com

I have seen different answers which are using

```
User.update_all(some_column: "bar")
```

But it will not work for me. Can anyone please guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: A concrete example would be: Update umar.tahir@xyz.com to umar.tahir@abc.com

I have to repeat this specific updation for all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple but not very fast solution:

```
User.find_each { |usr| usr.update(email: usr.email.sub('@xyz.com',  '@abc.com')) }
```

When there are a lot of users without a '@xyz.com' email address in the table then your might want to only load matching users in the first place:

```
User
  .where("email LIKE '%@xyz.com'")
  .find_each { |usr| usr.update(email: usr.email.sub('@xyz.com',  '@abc.com')) }
```

The fastest solution would certainly be to update the records in pure SQL but the syntax might depend on the database engine you are using. And when your table is not too big (hundreds of thousands of records) it is probably not worth it to not use Rails.

Comment: I applied above command, in response it showed me a result set with updated values. But those values arent updated in db. Feels like User resultset that we got after applying where is deattached from db

Comment: Also I made an update in your suggestion, I changed find_each with each. It was throwing error nil on find_each

Comment: Can you please let me know how, I make sure that results get reflected in db?

Comment: Thanks I found the problem, It was on code level.